# After updating Kubuntu 20.04 to the latest, login results in system halt

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, updates, kubuntu

board is ROG Strix Z390-F Gaming, with latest BIOS update
Intel i9 9900K
RAM: 32GB Dual Channel G-Skill Trident Z RGB (F4-3200C16-16GTZR x2)
Graphics: NVidia GeForce RTX 2080 Super (8GB)

The system booted fine, after maybe a month of not booting to Linux. (Dual boots with Windows 10) after running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
shutdown -r now
```

the OS upgraded all upgradable packages, then rebooted, loaded GRUB, then just went to a black screen.
From here, I rebooted, choosing advanced options for Ubuntu, chose recovery mode, and repaired all packages.
Another reboot got me to the Kubuntu login screen.
I logged in from there, and the system halted. No TTY access, and the numlock on my keyboard even stops functioning.

Only option is to pull the power cord, and boot fresh to do anything else.

Note that Windows 10 boots perfectly fine, and I never had this problem before today. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my particular problem, the resolution was to purge all nvidia packages, and install nvidia-driver-435. No idea why this resolved it, but my system is working normally now.